# Executing commands with subprocess while using tuples/lists?

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I'm trying to make a `terminal` while using [Replit](https://www.repl.it) (a collaborative browser based IDE) that is using `Ubuntu 5.13.12`. But, for some reason subprocess doesn't accept lists/tuples into running it. I tried using with `os.system` but i realized it only returns a value if it's using a string.

The code shown above only works in distros of Linux like `Ubuntu`, `Fedora`, `Debian`.

##### Python Simplified Terminal

```py
import termcolor;
import subprocess;
import os;

while (__name__ == '__main__'):
    _DEPENDENT_PROCESS = []
    _STRING_DIVISOR = " "

    terminal_input = input(termcolor.colored(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "blue", attrs=['bold']) + "$ ")
    if _STRING_DIVISOR in terminal_input:
      counted_arguments = terminal_input.count(_STRING_DIVISOR)
      splited_arguments = list(terminal_input.split(_STRING_DIVISOR, counted_arguments))
      _DEPENDENT_PROCESS, error = splited_arguments, None
    intrepeter = subprocess.run([_DEPENDENT_PROCESS], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    _terminal_output = intrepeter.stdout
    print(_terminal_output.decode('ascii'))
```

```
Error: Expected str, bytes, os.Paths, not lists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import termcolor;
import subprocess;
import os;

while (__name__ == '__main__'):
    terminal_input = input(termcolor.colored(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "blue", attrs=['bold']) + "$ ")
    intrepeter = subprocess.run(terminal_input.split(" "), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    _terminal_output = intrepeter.stdout
    print(_terminal_output.decode('ascii'),end="")
```

What's wrong with doing this? It works the way a terminal would for me.
Although I know it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: The problem is when you execute a command like ``echo “Hello World”`` it simply doesn’t work

Comment: Check the answer again, I updated my mistake. I'm splitting the string which returns a list. You can avoid all of this work by using shell=True, but you should probably shlex the output first.

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks for your answer

Comment: I would recommend using something like the autocomplete.py script I'm using in this project of mine https://github.com/mustansirgodhrawala/rst/blob/master/src/rst/autocomplete.py it'll help you catch arrow keypresses and tabs for autocomplete if you want it. Although you will need some funky implementation for quotes in this solution I've provided. I might do one today with the stuff weird for loops if you want it.